# Why rugby players try run to the center in-goal area?

Tags: rugby-union, rugby, rugby-league

It often happened that when a rugby player arrive with no pressure opponents try to take the oval to the center of the in-goal area.

The try is taken when the player enter in the in-goal area, so I do not understard why the players continue to run in this directions

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding [tag:rugby-league] to this question as it applies equally to league, and we don't have enough league questions :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because the conversion is taken from a point in-line with where the try is scored, at a distance chosen by the kicker. The important point to note is that a try is *not* scored "when the player enter in the in-goal area": the try is scored only when the ball is grounded with control in the in-goal area. The kick is obviously much easier if it's done from in front of the posts rather than far out by the touchline, so players will attempt to ground the ball as close to the posts as possible in order to make the conversion as easy as possible.

The actual wording is different in union and league; the relevant laws are [9.B.1(b)](http://laws.worldrugby.org/index.php?law=9.B.1&language=EN) for union:

> The [conversion] kick is taken on a line through the place where the try was scored in the field of play.

and [6.8](http://www.rugby-league.com/the_rfl/rules/laws_of_the_game/scoring) for league:

> A kick at goal after a try may be taken from any point on an imaginary line drawn parallel to the touch line in the field of play and through the point where the try was awarded.

Comment: Does the ball need to be "grounded with control"? Many times I have seen a ball almost dropped as the player dives over the line but he is able to get his hand on the ball and keep contact before it hits the ground. There is no way he is "in control" of the ball but it still counts as a try.

Comment: What I was always taught is that you have to apply downward pressure to the ball - i.e. it's not enough just to touch a ball in the in-goal area, but you have to be actively grounding it. Not sure how or if this has changed since I were a lad.

Comment: Thats what I have been taught as well, but downward pressure does not mean control.

Comment: Afaik you need to have one or the other. Doesn't this have its own question? It should.

Comment: You need to be applying downward pressure at the point where the ball first touches the ground. That is the control that is required, and when you've achieved that the try is scored and so you don't need to maintain control after that.